# Dockerfile Entrypoint no such file or directory: OCI not found

Tags: docker, cmd, dockerfile, docker-entrypoint

I have a Dockerfile with Entrypoint where I specify the config file variable and the executable file but it looks like Docker or Entrypoint doesn't recognize it. My `main.py` has to be executed with the config file.

```
ENTRYPOINT ["CONFIG_FILE=path/to/config.file ./main.py"]
```

always reproduce no such file or directory: OCI not found

Note: I have copied all the files in the current work directory already. `main.py` is an executable file. So I guess the problem is the `config variable` appended before the executable file. Does anyone know what is going on there? Also changing from `ENTRYPOINT` to `CMD` does not help as well.

Dockerfile

```
FROM registry.fedoraproject.org/fedora:34

WORKDIR /home

COPY . /home

ENTRYPOINT ["CONFIG_FILE=path/to/config.file ./main.py"]
```

Comment: Have you tried using the ENV directive to specify the config?

Comment: @ssc327 I did but maybe I didn't do it correctly or sth and it still doesn't not work.
```ENV path=path/to/config.file
ENTRYPOINT ["CONFIG_FILE=${path} ./main.py"]
```

Comment: Please share your dockerfile

Comment: @ssc327 I added it in my question

Comment: Have you tried FROM registry.fedoraproject.org/fedora:34 ENV CONFIG_FILE=path/to/config.file  WORKDIR /home COPY . /home ENTRYPOINT [" /home/main.py"

Comment: @ssc327 I think I duplicate the `config file` option in the `ENTRYPOINT`. Removing it works for me as in the answer. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just need to set an environment variable to a static string, use the Dockerfile `ENV` directive.

```sh
ENV CONFIG_FILE=/path/to/config.file
CMD ["./main.py"]
```

The Dockerfile `ENTRYPOINT` and `CMD` directives (and also `RUN`) have two forms.  You've used the JSON-array form; in that form, there is not a shell involved and you have to manually split out words.  (You are trying to run a command `CONFIG_FILE=... ./main.py`, where the executable file itself needs to include the `=` and space.)  If you don't use the JSON-array form you can use the shell form instead, and this form should work:

```sh
CMD CONFIG_FILE=/path/to/config.file ./main.py
```

In general you should prefer `CMD` to `ENTRYPOINT`.  There's a fairly standard pattern of using `ENTRYPOINT` to do first-time setup and then execute the `CMD`.  For example, if you expected the configuration file to be bind-mounted in, but want to set the variable only if it exists, you could write a shell script:

```sh
#!/bin/sh
# entrypoint.sh
#
# If the config file exists, set it as an environment variable.
CONFIG_FILE=/path/to/config.file
if [ -f "$CONFIG_FILE" ]; then
  export CONFIG_FILE
else
  unset CONFIG_FILE
fi

# Run the main container CMD.
exec "$@"
```

Then you can specify both the `ENTRYPOINT` (which sets up the environment variables) and the `CMD` (which says what to actually do)

```sh
# ENTRYPOINT must be JSON-array form for this to work
ENTRYPOINT ["./entrypoint.sh"]
# Any valid CMD syntax is fine
CMD ["./main.py"]
```

You can double-check the environment variable setting by providing an alternate `docker run` command

```sh
# (Make sure to quote things so the host shell doesn't expand them first)
docker run --rm my-image sh -c 'echo $CONFIG_FILE'
docker run --rm -v "$PWD:/path/to" my-image sh -c 'echo $CONFIG_FILE'
```

If having the same environment in one-off debugging shells launched by `docker exec` is important to you, of these approaches, only Dockerfile `ENV` will make the variable visible there.  In the other cases the environment variable is only visible in the main container process and its children, but the `docker exec` process isn't a child of the main process.